# How do i build a relationship between database and a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a bunch of zip codes. Each zip code has its own database. The tables in each database are only related to that particular zip code. I also have a customer database. Each customer can only be assigned to one zip code. Being assigned to a zip code, that customer has access to all the features/TABLES  of that particular zip code.

If I had all the zip codes and customers in one database I could easily join the tables using Foreign Keys / Primary Keys. But I feel it is more organized to keep each zip code separate as its own database. I choose it this way because each zip code is completely unique from one another.

I am new and have been watching tutorials but I only see table to table solutions. I would like to know how can I build a relationship between databases.

Comment: I would rethink your original design.  A separate database means a separate database; there *are no* relationships between that data.

Comment: ANd BTW, customers often have multiple zip codes in real life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: there is no way to establish relation between data in different databases.

Your design doesn't make things more organized; on the contrary, by creating multiple databases with similar - and related - data, you make it much more difficult to establish connections and to work with the data in an effective way.

Consider moving all data into one database, and adding "zip_code" field to tables so you can easily select data from each zip code as needed.

Comment: Better yet, add `customer_id` to each table.  Who says a customer will never change zip codes?

Comment: This might also be a good idea. But it is difficult to give further advice on the DB design without knowing more about the problem.

Comment: "there is no way to establish relation between data in different databases": Totally not true in MySQL. MySQL "databases" are just schemas, and you can query across them or have foreign keys between them.

Answer (score 1):

1. A "database" in MySQL is just a schema
2. You can query between and have foreign keys between schemas, just use the fully qualified name schema_name.table_name
3. I can't see a good reason to have zip codes spread among schemas. They should all be in the same table with a "country" column.